# How can I protect integer data on NSUserDefaults from hacking?

Tags: ios, iphone, security, nsuserdefaults

I have the paid content on my application on App Store. And I save it using the following code:

```
paidContentCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"paidContentCount"];
```

But it's easy to hack it. How can I protect integer data from hacking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try saving your content as string with `[NSString hash]` method, and after your app is loaded, compare paid content's hashes with value from `NSUserDefaults`

UPDATE: forgot that `[NSString hash]` returns NSInteger

Answer (score 3):

Never store such settings in `NSUserDefaults`! Use an iOS Keychain for it. Here is the [wrapper](https://github.com/carlbrown/PDKeychainBindingsController), which makes the biggest part of work.

Besides it, you can read [this article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1) from Ray Wenderlich - there are a lot of good ideas of basic security.

Comment: It's more complicated, and none of the ways is completely secure - if someone wants to hack your app - he'll definetely do it.

Comment: It's only one simple integer value. Really don't want to use third-party components to save it...

Comment: etolstoy, you are right, it won't be completely secure. But I want to find an easy way.

Comment: @Altaveron if you want to make it as easy, as possible, replace the integer value with string, which you can hardcode in your app. It's not as obvious to the attacker as integer value in NSUserDefaults. Besides, don't forget to change the Key name to something tricky.

Comment: Should I check "Have you added or made changes to encryption features since your last submission of this app?" to "Yes" on iTunes Connect if I use iOS Keychain?

Comment: @Altaveron, no, it's not necessary.

Comment: But why it's not necessary? `If I use the encryption available in the iOS or Mac OS X, do I still need to obtain U.S. government approval? What should I do about the source code, since I can’t provide it to them?`   `You still need to submit your app to the U.S. Bureau of Industry and Security (BIS) for approval because they want to know how you are using encryption in your particular app, even though they have already approved the encryption in the iOS and Mac OS X. You are responsible for obtaining separate approval.`

Comment: @Altaveron, as I know, the use of iOS Keychain is one of the basic functions of the app. you need to check this only if you embed your own cryptography logic. Three of my apps use Keychain, and I have never checked this when uploading new version.